# Entity framework get (unique) number of times ID is present in event

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We have shopping list DataTable that holds ingredients. One ingredient can be added to shopping list more then once.

What I would like to select is: on how many shopping lists is one ingredient present. Even if ingredient is present multiple times on one shopping list query should return 1.
In short: I need COUNT of ShoppingListIngredients that contains ingredientId (no matter, once or multiple times)

I have tried like this:

```
var usersShoppingListIngredients = context.ShoppingListIngredients
                .Where(sli => sli.ShoppingList.userId == userId)
                .GroupBy(sli => sli.ingredientId)
                .Select(sli => new
                {
                    itemId = sli.Key,
                    item = sli.FirstOrDefault().CodingKeys.Ingredients.FirstOrDefault(i => i.languageId == languageId).coding,
                    itemsCount = sli.Count(),
                    percent = [Tell_Me_How] * 100 / totalPurchases
                }).OrderByDescending(r => r.itemsCount);
```

But it returns me false value - it returns number of all occurrences when multiple values are inserted.

I am using Entity Framework 4.0.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just use `sli.Count() * 100 / totalPurchases`. the `ShoppingListIngredients` seems like a join table (shoppinglistid PK, ingredientid PK, userid PK) , when you group the table by ingredientId, there should be no multiple shopping list id in there. If you can provide sample data or what the class looks like that would be great.

Comment: sli.Count() still returns total number of occurrences for each ID. If I group by ShoppingListIngredients and ingredient is inserted 3 times then I get 3. I need COUNT of ShoppingListIngredients that contains ingredientId (no matter, once or multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

Try this `itemsCount = sli.DistinctBy(s => s.ShoppingListId).Count()`

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately I don't have DistinctBy function. Probably not EF 4.0 feature. Also, when I try to use Distinct, it doesn't let me use parameters. Error: Cannot convert labda expression to type "system.collections.generic.IE.quality.comparer"<myEntity> because it is not a delegate type